# How do I disable inclusion of passed down JavaScript and Stylesheet files in view.yml for a module?

Tags: syntax, symfony1

In symfony1.1, I develop a module that shall not include any of the passed down javascripts and stylesheets of its application.

I hence I created a module-specific `view.yml`, yet I cannot find the syntax for disabling them.

My original question involved only JavaScript and CSS. But now I want to remove metas and http_tags as well. For some reason I get for:

```
all:
  http_metas: [-*]
  metas: [-*]
```

the actual tag

```
<meta name="0" content="-*" />
```

Does anyone know what's different here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exclude all the passed down javascripts and stylesheets, or remove just specific ones.

For example:

```
indexSuccess:
  stylesheet: [-style]
```

or:

```
indexSuccess:
  stylesheet: [-*]
```

Comment: This works as expected for javascript and stylesheet. Now I want to do it for metas and http_metas as well, yet then I get an actual meta tag `<meta name="0" content="-*" />`. Do you know what to do here as well?

Answer (score 0):

[It does not seem possible for metas](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/34):

---

> You may find yourself wanting to remove default meta tags for specific modules within your application. This isn't possible through view.yml or module.yml ... The solution is to extend the sfWebResponse class, overriding the getMetas() method. This allows us to filter out unwanted tags without affecting special behaviour, e.g. for the title tag.

```
class myWebResponse extends sfWebResponse
{
  public function getMetas()
  {
    $meta_tags = $this->parameter_holder->getAll('helper/asset/auto/meta');
    if ($this->getContext()->getModuleName() == 'special_module' && array_key_exists('bad_meta', $meta_tags)) {
      unset($meta_tags['bad_meta']);
    }
    return $meta_tags;
  }
}
```